# Colors from image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have some squares,each with 4 colors on them(red,green,blue,etc).
I want to make a program that can recognize the colors(through the webcam),memorize them in a text file or something and then,if it sees the same square again to recognize it.
I tried to make some RGB limitations for each color and when the program processes a picture to compare each square's RGB with my limitations.

The problem I seem to have is that in different environments (more or less light) the algorithm fails. It either sees orange as green or doesn't recognize red or other problems like that.

Is there any better way to compare colors, or should I just keep trying on finding better limitations for each color?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure Auto-White-Balance is On ?

Comment: The color of an image is relative to the color of lights in the environments. As @HenkHolterman says either white balance helps, or you need to sample white and use that to pre-process the image to correct the colors.

Answer (score 2):

Convert from RGB to HSV, as an initial step (it's a better color space for image processing/comparison operations - see [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/why-do-we-use-the-hsv-colour-space-so-often-in-vision-and-image-processing) for details, or the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) for more general info on this color space.)

The conversion between RGB and HSV is simple, and there are plenty of sample formula and code you can find with a quick search.  After that, use just the Hue channel for comparisons, for the reasons described in the prior links.  You should have much better results across different lighting conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! The conversion from RGB to HSV seems to help me a lot! @HenkHolterman, never heard before of Auto-White-Balance, but I google'd it and gave me some new ideas for my project!